# How to avoid windows registration hotkeys occupying normal keyboard input？

Tags: python, winapi, hotkeys

I'm writing a gizmo using python,and I added a hotkey control function in it.Hotkeys can be registered, released and used normally.

The problem is that:

**When I set the hotkey to be a single keyboard key, it disables the key's normal input function(Even if I turn off the hotkey switch),I have to unregister this key to get it back to normal.**

The following is the main code involved:

```
class HotkeyListener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, root):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.root = root
        self.user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
        self.hkey_dict = {}  # alt-->0x0001,ctrl-->0x0002,shift-->0x0004,win-->0x0008
        self.hkey_queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                if not self.hkey_queue.empty():
                    hkey = self.hkey_queue.get()
                    hkey()
                msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()

                """Process the message received when the hotkey is turned off --> remove it directly, 
                otherwise it will accumulate until the hotkey is turned on and continue to execute
                """
                if not Global.hotkey_use:  
                    self.user32.PeekMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0, win32con.PM_REMOVE)
                if self.user32.PeekMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0, win32con.PM_REMOVE):
                    if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:  # Whether hotkey message
                        if msg.wParam in self.hkey_dict:   # Is id in the dictionary
                            flag()
                            # Execute hotkey function
                            self.root.after(0, self.hkey_dict[msg.wParam]["func"])

                self.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
                self.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))
                time.sleep(0.01)  # Reduce CPU usage

        finally:
            for ID in self.hkey_dict:
                self.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, ID)
```

In general, Global.hotkey_use can only make the hotkey untriggerable, but it cannot restore the key to normal.

While I can unregister them both every time the hotkeys are turned off and re-register them when they are on, this doesn't look good.Since I don't have a deep understanding of windows API,so I'm looking for a better way to solve this problem.

looking forward to answer.

sincere thanks!

I tried to put the judgment of Global.hotkey_use in different positions,but still no expected effect.

```
            while True:
                if not self.hkey_queue.empty():
                    hkey = self.hkey_queue.get()
                    hkey()
                msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()

                if self.user32.PeekMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0, win32con.PM_REMOVE):
                    if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
                        if msg.wParam in self.hkey_dict:
                            if Global.hotkey_use:
                                flag()
                                self.root.after(0, self.hkey_dict[msg.wParam]["func"])
```

Comment: That sounds like it's doing exactly what it should be doing? What do the docs say?

Comment: The docs doesn't say anything about key input function conflicts.Perhaps its logic is that when a key is registered and bound to a function, the key only has the function of executing this function.But I hope that the key input function should be something more low-level,should not be blocked by bound functions

Comment: The function works fine, and Hotkeys should avoid themselves in conflict with input keys. Also, how to determine what the user wants to input if there is a conflict?

Comment: for example,I set the A key as a hotkey,and Global.hotkey_use is off.When I want to spell the word apple using the keyboard normally, I can't type the letter "A", key presses don't give any feedback unless I unregister.This will affect the user to use the computer to do other things, such as editing documents.

Comment: [UnregisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterhotkey) or consider [Keyboard Accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/keyboard-accelerators).

Comment: You've registered a hotkey, that means the key is unavailable for other use. Seems to be working as designed?

Comment: OK,I get it, it looks like it's normal work.I have to think of another way.

Answer (score -1):

As we said, the function works fine. But you can consider [Keyboard Accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/keyboard-accelerators) which is for an application.

The following code works for me.

```
    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg) && msg.message != WM_CHAR)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Update:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                //here is the function for IDM_ABOUT
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Think you for your help,I also looked up some information about Keyboard Accelerators yesterday when you mentioned it in the comment section.but it is difficult for me,I know very little about Cpp, how it is linked to my function?

Comment: You can write your function at WM_COMMAND->IDM_ABOUT for my example.

Comment: This is phenomenally useless. Clearly, the OP is registering a hotkey because they are interested in observing a key combination **globally**. This code requires that a particular window has the input focus. It does literally **nothing** if any other window has the input focus.

Comment: @IInspectable, I mentioned it in my answer and then what does the OP say?

Comment: They asked how it relates to their problem. And you never responded to that in a way that was helpful. Might want to read [answer].